# About Info.plist file and Xcode 5

Tags: ios, app-store, key, plist, xcode5

I have some questions regarding the information I should include in my project's `Info.plist` file before submitting the app:

A) About `CFBundleIcons`: I see this key when I open the file in Xcode as source code and the xml format is displayed but, when I open it as property list, I only see an `Icon files (iOS 5)` entry, is that correct? On the other hand, I've changed the app icons I firstly had in the General tab of the target settings, and the `Info.plist` file keeps listing the old app icons as well, and the new icons I added do not have the `.png` extension in their name... should I handle this information manually, or did I something wrong when I changed the icons in the target's settings? Should the names include the `png` extension? Should I list all versions of an icon (standard and @2x), or just the name for the standard is enough?

B) Regarding `UIRequiresPersistentWifi` key, Apple's docs say that

> Include this key if your app requires a Wi-Fi connection

I'm not sure if I have to include this key: my app performs network operations but they could be done via WWAN, not only via Wi-Fi. And not all my app's features need network connection to be performed.

C) About `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key. I have in turn some questions here: Apple says that

> The value of the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`key is either an array or a dictionary that contains additional keys identifying features your app requires (or specifically prohibits).

What do they mean when they say "features your app requires": those features which the app won't work at all without them, or all those features that your app can use? For example: my app includes an option for listening the device's location. It is an optional functionality, users can enable and disable it. I check `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]` when the user enables the option. I've no set the `location-services` value in the `plist` file and the app has been tested and the feature works, and the compiler has never complained. Should I include the value if I want to submit the app?

Something similar happens with another capabilities, for example `microphone` and `still-camera`. I use `UIImagePickerController` at some point of the app, as well as the microphone for speech recognition, but that are also optional functions of the app that the user has to select, they don't affect its overall operation. And I neither have included such values in the `plist` yet and they are working...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A: If you want to publish iPhone app only you need provide the 2 icon's(@1x, @2x),Now I think @1x is not for necessary, if you want to publish Both iPad & iPhone, you may need to provide 4 icon. But if you dont care about the quality 1 icon is OK.

B:This line UIRequiresPersistentWifi is not necessary.

C:Same as B) This line UIRequiresPersistentWifi is not necessary. if you have more require from iOS system.